# scrollview inside view with multiple textfields

Tags: ios, swift3

I have  drag and dropped a scrollview, and this scrollview will occupy entire screen so its constraints are 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 to all 4 sides.
However, I am adding 25 textfields. As my form is very big, once I reach at bottom I just cannot drag my textfields outside of the scene. I need my scene to be large enough, how to solve this?

```
import Foundation
class AddStoreController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    var id: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //let photo3 = UIImage(named: "defaultph")!
        //imageToAdd.image = photo3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your controller or scene in your storyboard, go to the Size inspector and switch the simulated size from Fixed to freeform. You can now adjust the height